# Regex to allow decimal numbers greater than 0 and less than 100

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to enter value greater than `0` and less than `100` and i am using the following regex:

```
/^(0+)?(99(\.99?)?|(\.99?)?|\.[0-9]+|0?[0-9](\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(0+)?[0-9][0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)$/
```

this regex does not complain about zero but 0.01 is a valid value.

Basically, I am trying to get the value in a `00.00` format and it is also acceptable to have values like `0.01, 00.01, ... 99.99` but strictly numbers and dot only.

I am using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [html](/questions/tagged/html)

Comment: it can be some time but not necessary that i need to have in floating format.. thanks

Comment: did you want to allow `0.00` or `00.00`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?!0?0\.00$)\d{1,2}\.\d{2}$
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/10

Comment: This matches 00.00 but i dont want this also  0.00,0,00.00,00.0. these have got no meaning.

Comment: but these values are also acceptable : 2, 2.5, 2.00, 2.01. basically upto 99.99 is acceptable. i am sorry if i had confused you with my question.

Comment: This matches 0.0,00.0
0.0
00.0

Comment: .85,.10 these are also valid values but the above one does not accept this, could you please look in to... but if i enter 0.58 or 0.25 or 0.85 it accepts..

Comment: Thanks for the patience and help.. it works now as i expected. very kind of you...pls give me some times will check with few more values and post here the results

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, very kind of

Answer (score 3):

So why do you have to beat your self up with a complex regex. Why not a number comparison?

```
function validNum (num) {
   num = parserFloat(num);

   return num > 0 && num < 100;
}
```

Want only two decimal places ?

```
function validNum (num) {
   num = parseFloat((num + "").replace(/^(.*\.\d\d)\d*$/, '$1'));

   return num > 0 && num < 100;
}
```

[Test Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uxocgbqa/1/)

```
.5:      true
..5    : false
.005   : false
0.05   : true
99.99  : true
00.01  : true
00.00  : false
0.00   : false
00.0   : false
100.00 : false
```

Comment: Definitely the right approach, but `parseFloat` may not be ideal because it will ignore cruft at the end. Also, he may not want to truncate the decimal portion to two digits, but rather only **accept** input with two digits.

Comment: @torazaburo the second function is based on what he said. `I am trying to get the value in a 00.00 format`, with the second one parseFloat can't do anything tricky with the number because its formatted to 00.00 before its placed in a parseFloat

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want to allow `0.00` or `00.00`

```
^(?!00?\.00$)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

OR

```
^(?!00?\.00$)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/11)

Negative lookahead at the start `(?!00?\.00$)` asserts that the number going to match wouldn't be `00.00` or `0.00`

Comment: but these values are also acceptable : 2,
2.5,
2.00,
2.01. basically upto 99.99 is acceptable. i am sorry if i had confused you with my question

Comment: yep it allows `2.00`, `2.01`. That's what you asked.. GReater than 0.00 upto 99.99. Could you explain your question briefly.

Comment: it does not allow 2, 3, 5 which are valid.

Comment: just make the decimal part optional. See my update. `\.\d{1,2}` allows one or two digits after the decimal part.